# Connection timout when trying to connect to the server with Fez Connect Shield

Tags: c#, sockets, embedded, client

I'm using a [FEZ Domino](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/133) with [FEZ Connect Shield](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/261) attached. This is my code trying to connect to the server application on my laptop through the ethernet port:

```
private const string ServerIPAddress = "192.168.153.206";
private const int port = 2000;

WIZnet_W5100.Enable(SPI.SPI_module.SPI1, (Cpu.Pin)FEZ_Pin.Digital.Di10,(Cpu.Pin)FEZ_Pin.Digital.Di7, true);         

using(var clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ServerIPAddress);
    IPAddress ipAddress = entry.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    Debug.Print("Connecting to server: " + serverEndPoint + ".");

    clientSocket.SendTimeout = 3000;
    clientSocket.Connect(serverEndPoint);

    Debug.Print("Connected to server");

    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");
    clientSocket.Send(msg);
}
```

At "clientSocket.Connect(serverEndPoint)" I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type "System.Exception" occurred in GHIElectronics.NETMF.W5100.dll
Additional information: Timeout occurs during connection establishment
```

When i connect my laptop to another laptop, i can ping the server application and it will respond so i believe that the problem is not on the server application.

Help Please

Comment: Can your laptop make a connetion to port 2000?

Comment: Yes I can, from laptop2 i use google chrome and typing "192.168.153.206:2000" in the address bar and getting a simple page back

Comment: Does the Debug.Print("Connecting to server: ... line seem to have the right information?

Comment: Also, silly question, but are you able to connect to your FEZ Domino via ethernet?

Comment: I found the problem, it seems that you have to give the fez connect shield an ip address, submask and gateway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it seems that you have to give the fez connect shield an ip address, submask and gateway :)